# format hadoop namenode gives error cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I am trying to install and configure single node hadoop cluster on my pc on cygwin. Cygwin has been properly installed and configured but hadoop configuration is giving me tough time.

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

gives me Could not find or load main class `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode`

I have gone through several solved questions but none seem to help me.

Here is the content of my bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_05
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Chetan/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Chetan/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw $(hadoop classpath)):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

I have also export `$JAVA_HOME` in hadoop-env.sh as well and echo `$JAVA_HOME` is working fine.

Comment: Its soved by changing the HADOOP_INSTALL to /cygdrive/c/hadoop-2.7,1

Answer (score 0):

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/path_to_hadoop_location

# for example:
# export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/xxx/hadoop-x.x.xx

then source ~/.bashrc
```

Refer to :

[Could not find or load main class when trying to format namenode; hadoop installation on MAC OS X 10.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017937/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-when-trying-to-format-namenode-hadoop-install)